# How to achieve resizable parent height when subviews(labels) are added?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way of achieving parent height resizable when adding labels. `Parent View1` should resize its height when labels are added and `Parent View2` also.

```
Parent View1
   label1
   label2
Parent View2
   label1
   label2
```

Comment: you can achieve this by auto layouts easily.

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman Can you please elaborate more on this.

Comment: @Swamy, create height constraint of your view , add IBOutlet of that height constraint, then increase height of that view using height constraint before adding the label. Now create label on that view. Here you can achieve this through programatically or through xib.

Comment: @Swamy - this is very, very basic auto-layout functionality. In fact, if you use `UIStackView` it is almost completely done for you.  What have you tried, and what are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

ParentView1 has its top, left, right and bottom
label1 has its top, left, right with respect to its parent, now you have to set label1's bottom to parentView1's bottom.
this will update the parentView1's bottom with label1's bottom
same you can do with parentView2

This this by without giving the bottom to the parentView1 and give some fixed height to the label1, and then update the bottom of label1 with parentView1's bottom.